# Slow Boot and Battery Problem in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, boot, ati, battery

I'm a new ubuntu user and loved using it. But I'm now facing a problem using it.
i.e., Battery Draining very quickly. ( Mine is Dell inspiron 15 - 4GB RAM - 500 HDD - AMD RADEON HD 7670 graphics. - Dual boot alongside windows8 )
It will come around 3hrs in windows8, but only 1:30 hr in ubuntu.
I found that its defaultly using Intel graphics and hence I installed AMD Catalyst drivers and also tlp power management tool and hurray I got around 4hr battery backup.
But that joy disappeared very soon, since I installed AMD catalyst drivers my ubuntu booting became very very slow and that's very annoying.

Is there any solution that I can be solved both issues 
< or >
I've to sacrifice one for the other ! :(

Will become your fan if you make my both issues solved !
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably installed tlp and without uninstalling laptop-mode-tools which came by default. You can't use both of them at the same time. Uninstall tlp, check if laptop-mode-tools are installed using the Software Center (install if they aren't), install powertop, plug out yur laptop, run powertop and check in the "Tunables" section if the power saving features are working. You can also try to purge (sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*), and then reinstall (sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress) the AMD drivers.